# Run isc-dhcp-server from docker container

Tags: docker, networking, dockerfile

What I want: Docker container offering an IP address of 192.254.5.12 (and only that). The host machine shall than offer this on a physical interface.
The host machine is then connected to a DUT.

I would like to run a dhcp-server inside a docker container.

[image]

Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get install isc-dhcp-common libdns-export1110 libirs-export161 libisc-export1105 libisccfg-export163 policycoreutils selinux-utils cron exim4-base exim4-config exim4-daemon-light gsasl-common guile-2.2-libs libgc1 libgnutls-dane0 libgsasl7 libidn11 libmailutils7 libntlm0 libpython3.9 libunbound8 mailutils mailutils-common psmisc isc-dhcp-server
RUN   echo "authoritative; subnet 192.254.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 { range 192.254.5.12 192.254.5.12; default-lease-time 600; max-lease-time 7200;}" > /etc/dhcpd.conf
RUN   echo "INTERFACESv4='eth0'" > /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server
```

dhpcd.conf

```
authoritative; 
subnet 192.254.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 
     { range 192.254.5.12 192.254.5.12; 
       default-lease-time 600; 
       max-lease-time 7200;
      }
```

ip addr:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
113: eth0@if114: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.17.0.2/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

When I run the `service isc-dhcp-server start` I get (from syslog):

```
Feb  7 13:02:19 f87e46881008 rsyslogd: activation of module imklog failed [v8.2102.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2145 ]
Feb  7 13:02:19 f87e46881008 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.2102.0" x-pid="232" x-info="https://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Feb  7 13:02:25 f87e46881008 dhcpd[269]: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
Feb  7 13:02:25 f87e46881008 dhcpd[269]: 
Feb  7 13:02:25 f87e46881008 dhcpd[269]: No subnet declaration for eth0 (172.17.0.2).
Feb  7 13:02:25 f87e46881008 dhcpd[269]: ** Ignoring requests on eth0.  If this is not what
Feb  7 13:02:25 f87e46881008 dhcpd[269]:    you want, please write a subnet declaration
Feb  7 13:02:25 f87e46881008 dhcpd[269]:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
Feb  7 13:02:25 f87e46881008 dhcpd[269]:    to which interface eth0 is attached. **
Feb  7 13:02:25 f87e46881008 dhcpd[269]: 
Feb  7 13:02:25 f87e46881008 dhcpd[269]: 
Feb  7 13:02:25 f87e46881008 dhcpd[269]: Not configured to listen on any interfaces!
Feb  7 13:02:25 f87e46881008 dhcpd[269]: 
Feb  7 13:02:25 f87e46881008 dhcpd[269]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
Feb  7 13:02:25 f87e46881008 dhcpd[269]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
Feb  7 13:02:25 f87e46881008 dhcpd[269]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
Feb  7 13:02:25 f87e46881008 dhcpd[269]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
Feb  7 13:02:25 f87e46881008 dhcpd[269]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging.
Feb  7 13:02:25 f87e46881008 dhcpd[269]: 
Feb  7 13:02:25 f87e46881008 dhcpd[269]: exiting.
```

My take so far:

I guess I need to change the IP address of the container, but how do i do that in the dockerfile? This dockerfile is executed as part of several tests so I cant attach IP-address as a flag, that would destroy other tests.

Comment: For a DHCP server, you'd kind of have to run it on an isolated physical network, no?  It seems like there are a lot of host-network considerations here, and adding the layer of Docker networking just makes it more complicated.  Can you run this task directly on the host?  (Is there any programming-related question here, or is it just about trying to run dhcpd in this particular environment?)

Comment: I have several host machines and I would like to avoid make any changes on them. Everything should be included in the docker image.